# ERROR: Fetching the page failed because SSL handshake error

Tags: php, twitter

In my site am using facebook open graph and twitter card, when we share content using facebook this working fine but using twitter summary card when i validate url uing twitter card validator getting this error

> ERROR: Fetching the page failed because SSL handshake error

any idea how to resolve this error. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the URL? How have you checked your SSL certificate?

Comment: (https://craftedusa.com) , Yes i checked my ssl at (https://www.ssllabs.com/) site nothing is wrong with my ssl certificate got A rating. Actually i am implemented twitter card in my site and validate the url using twitter validator using (https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) link then i got the above error